# Terrain making in unity

Tags: unity, terrain, minecraft-modding

I'm making a minecraft-like game, I'm trying to make a terrain made of cubes, but copying and pasting the same cube takes too much time and uses too much of my pc's RAM. So, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some code? Seeing how you do things, might help others help you.

Comment: the only code i've made is in which i can change the cube texture, that's all.

Comment: Well Yassine you wont be able to do what you want without code. Duplicating cubes in the editor will get you nowhere. Start reading here: http://alexstv.com/index.php/voxelmetric-documentaion and here is a git-hub to the code: https://github.com/Voxelmetric/Voxelmetric.

Comment: You are not going to copy paste your way to a game unfortunately.  I am voting to close, as questions about how to get started are off-topic here.  Please come back with a more specific question in the future.

Comment: I think my question was specific and clear Jon, and I also think that forums like this one are where we ask questions. :)

Comment: The answer is "don't copy paste", the solution is much more complicated and would require a great deal of effort to explain to you, as you provide nothing to build on.  My point is, you need to do some more research into this area, and come back with a code base that we can help you build on.  As it stands now, we would have to provide you with the entire foundation to get started.

Comment: @YassineBouzaiane This isn't a forum (in the traditional sense) and there are fairly strict rules about what is and isn't considered on-topic here (see the [help]).

Comment: I do think there's a reasonable question here, probably, but you need to refine it. What do you want suggestions *for*? For dealing with the time-consuming process of copy-pasting objects? For dealing with the memory overhead of having all those objects loaded into memory at once? Both of those are valid, if separate, questions; given the answers that have been posted already I'd lean towards focusing *this* post on the former question and making a new post about the latter question (be sure to provide more details about the specifics of your problem though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't copy and paste the cubes by hand. Create one cube for each block-type you have, make them into prefabs, and then write a script which `Instantiate`s your cube prefabs over and over again when the game starts.

Here is a small example script to get you going. It will spawn a 10x10x10 block of the prefab you assign to it.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MapLayoutNew : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;

    void Start () {
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {            
            for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
                     Instantiate(cubePrefab, new Vector3(x, y, z), this.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

This method will only work on a small scale. If you are trying to build something with as many cubes in the scene as Minecraft has, the performance will suffer because you will have way too many game objects in your scene. Remember that Minecraft is not built with a stock game-engine like Unity. The graphic engine was tailor-made to allow for a 100% procedural and changeable environment.

When you want to do something similar in Unity, you will have to apply some performance enhancement tricks to keep the framerate bearable. One is to turn multiple adjacent cubes into one game-object with a procedurally-generated mesh. Another is to disable any cubes the player can't see and enable them when they become visible.